# Can't Simplify an expression with lot of Arg($N$) with $N$ is a real number

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm struggling to simplify this expression.

```
Assuming[
 t > 0 && Element[N1, PositiveIntegers] && 
  Element[N2, PositiveIntegers], 
 ComplexExpand[
  Abs[-((E^(-I N2 t) (N2 - N1 N2))/(N1 N2)) - (
     2 E^(1/2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[
         N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(-N1 + 
      2 Sqrt[N1] N2 - 4 N1 N2 - N2^2 + 
      Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
      N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) + (
     2 E^(1/2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 - Sqrt[
         N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(
     N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2 + 
      Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
      N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2])]^2]]
```

where N1 and N2 are natural numbers, and t is positive real. After I ComplexExpand, I obtain  a very long expression:

[image]

where (if i *show all*) I see lots of Arg(...), so **Arguments of real numbers** (which is 0, but Mathematica seems to not know).

If the expression was shorter, I could get rid of all with *FullSimplify*, but if I do it, Mathematica keeps evaluating for ages without giving me a result.

QUESTION: How to tell Mathematica to set all this Arg(...) to 0, so I can *FullSimplify* faster?

NOTE: I'm 100% sure that all numbers in Arg() are REAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You raised an important problem (I also face with it quite often.). The following

```
 Assuming[t > 0 && Element[N1, PositiveIntegers] &&  Element[N2, PositiveIntegers], 
 ComplexExpand[ Abs[-((E^(-I N2 t) (N2 - N1 N2))/(N1 N2)) - (
 2 E^(1/2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(-N1 +  2 Sqrt[N1] N2 - 4 N1 N2 - N2^2 + 
  Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
  N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) + (
 2 E^(1/2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 - Sqrt[  N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(
 N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2 + 
  Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
  N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2])]^2]]/.{Arg[N1] -> 0, Arg[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4 N1*N2 + N2^2] -> 0}
```

works well, cancelling all `Arg`s and shortening the output from 8 MB to 0.7 MB. I'd like to notice that `Arg[-1]!=0` as well as other negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem

Comment: Or since the OP knows that all arguments are zero, just `{Arg[_] -> 0}`

Comment: The argument of the OP " Arguments of real numbers (which is 0, but Mathematica seems to not know" is not correct. I'd like to notice that `Arg[-1]!=0` as well as  of other negative numbers one more time. We have to ground it by `Resolve[ForAll[{N1, N2}, {N1, N2} \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
  N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4 N1*N2 + N2^2 >= 0]]` which results in `True`. This verification is valid for real `{N1,N2}>1` too.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
stuff= -((E^(-I N2 t) (N2 - N1 N2))/(N1 N2)) - (2 E^(1/
        2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 + 
         Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(-N1 + 
    2 Sqrt[N1] N2 - 4 N1 N2 - N2^2 + 
    Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
    N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + 
       N2^2]) + (2 E^(1/
        2 I (-Sqrt[N1] - N2 - 
         Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]) t) N2)/(N1 - 
    2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2 + 
    Sqrt[N1] Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2] - 
    N2 Sqrt[N1 - 2 Sqrt[N1] N2 + 4 N1 N2 + N2^2]);
```

The following takes about 7 seconds

```
Simplify[TrigToExp[Abs[ComplexExpand[stuff]]^2], 
 t > 0 && N1 \[Element] PositiveIntegers && N2 \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

And returns a comparitivly compact:
[image]

```
(*Abs[-2*(1 + E^(I*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2]*t) - 2*E^((I/2)*(Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2])*t))*Sqrt[N1]*
     N2 - 4*E^((I/2)*(Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2])*t)*N1^(3/2)*N2 + 
    (1 + E^(I*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2]*t) - 2*E^((I/2)*(Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2])*t))*N2^2 + 
    2*E^((I/2)*(Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2])*t)*N1^2*(1 + 4*N2) - 
    (-1 + E^(I*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2]*t))*N2*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2] + 
    (-1 + E^(I*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2]*t))*Sqrt[N1*(N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2)] + 
    N1*(1 + 4*N2 + E^(I*Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2]*t)*(1 + 4*N2) + 
      2*E^((I/2)*(Sqrt[N1] - N2 + Sqrt[N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2])*t)*(-1 - 4*N2 + N2^2))]^2/(4*N1^2*(N1 - 2*Sqrt[N1]*N2 + 4*N1*N2 + N2^2)^2)*)
```